# Por que no funciona cuando uso las medias queries

Tags: css, css3, mediaqueries

soy nuevo en desarrollo web y tengo un problema, que al poner un texto en responsive no se ajusta como las medidas indicadas, cualquier sugerencia o ayuda lo agradecería mucho
ESE ES EN CSS

```
.d-flex .text-justify{
    font-size: 100px;
    color: whitesmoke;

}
```

Y ESTE EN MEDIA QUERIES

```
@media only screen (min-width:576px) and (max-width:767px){
    .d-flex .text-justify{
        font-size: 20px;
        color: whitesmoke;
    }
```

Comment: Agrega tu HTML.

Comment: ... y si estás usando Bootstrap. ¿cómo y dónde lo estás declarando?

Comment: Es asi: <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <p class="text-justify">Texto de ejemplo.</p>

Comment: Y no solo sucede con este, tambien me pasa con las imagenes, será que ahago algo mal en el css?

Comment: Te falta cerrar el } media query